# Create searcher in js of images

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to creat a searcher in javascript. I've got 20 images of flags with different ids. My idea is to have an input where the user type the name of the country (this will be the id in the img tag) and it'll show the img.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

So suppose you got the input search value:

```
var value = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

Now you can insert it somewhere:

```
var imageBox = document.getElementById("app");
var str = `<img alt="${value}" id=`${value}`>`
imageBox.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
```

Hopefully, I´ve helped you somehow...

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can create an image searcher using RxJS. Please check the sample code I have added below to give you an overview of how it can be done.

`app.component.html`

```
<input #search placeholder="Search" name="seacher" />

<div *ngIf="searchedImage">
  <img [src]="searchedImage" />
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("search", { static: false }) search: ElementRef;

  imageList = [
    { name: "Image 1", image: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" },
    { name: "Image 2", image: "https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" },
    { name: "Image 3", image: "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300" },
    { name: "Image 4", image: "https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300" }
  ];

  searchQuery: string = "";
  searchedImage: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, "keyup")
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
          this.searchedImage = this.imageList.find(
            (item) => item.name === this.search.nativeElement.value
          )?.image;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```